# BigQuery: is the timestamp associate with the Google Analytics view Time zone country or territory?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, timestamp-with-timezone

When requesting BigQuery 'SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime)', I'm getting strange (no consistency) results for the 'visitStartTime'.

My question is: is the timestamp associate with BigQuery results which are displayed for the Google Analytics are linked to set up of view Time zone country or territory's view?

Thanks four your kindly help,
Sébastien

Answer (score 2):

`visitStartTime` and all other similar fields are Unixtime-seconds since 1970, which is a timezone free notation, as it's UTC. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089

To further convert to any timezone you need to use a timezone function.

Comment: Thank you @pentium10, but so my data is not accurate with the time which is displayed in the Google Analytics view :-(

Comment: this is a major issue because the data is not consistency between fields which are Unixtime and the data that are displayed in the Google Analytics console; so which data should I trust?

Comment: post another question with both print screen, maybe you identified the wrong pair, so far I never met a project where this was an issue, maybe you read it wrong.